# Getting string length from a string in file

Tags: c

I have a dynamic structure array of a few strings, say `char *str1`, `char *str2`, `char *str3`. 
I have to get strings from a file and give each struct member memory based on the string lengths.

How would I approach this? 
Thanks very much.

Comment: With ease. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hello.
I have tried reading the string from the file into a temporary char variable, getting strlen of that, the using fseek and going back to the beginning of the string and allocating the strlen amount of memory to the array.
But it seems terribly clunky, is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean with 'dynamic structure array'? Is it an array of structures or an array of strings (=array of char pointers)?

If it's just an array of pointers, you would simply call malloc() for every entry and then assign the string.

```
char *strings[5];

void insert_string(int array_index, char *string, int length)
{
    strings[array_index] = malloc(length);
    strcpy(strings[array_index], string, length);
}
```

Of course you'd have to add code to prevent your array from overflowing, or automatically keeping track of the index...

Comment: Sorry, I am an amateur.
I have an array of structures containing strings. But I dont think it matters in this case.
Thanks for the snippet, ill try to implement this.